# Twig GlobalsInterface breaks Symfony Debug Toolbar

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Symfony 4.3.1

I have a Twig-Extension in which I add variables globally to Twig. As soon as I implement the `Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface` in my class the Symfony debug toolbar just renders 'An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar.' The variables get perfectly added to the global scope though.

Here is my extension:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface;

class GlobalVarsExtension extends AbstractExtension implements GlobalsInterface
{
    protected $em;

    protected $tokenStorage;

    protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }


    public function getGlobals()
    {
        $globalVars = [];

        if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            if (null !== $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
                $globalVars['user'] = $token->getUser();
            }
        }

        return $globalVars;
    }
}
```

This is the interface I implement:

```php
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of Twig.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Twig\Extension;

/**
 * Enables usage of the deprecated Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension::getGlobals() method.
 *
 * Explicitly implement this interface if you really need to implement the
 * deprecated getGlobals() method in your extensions.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
interface GlobalsInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns a list of global variables to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return array An array of global variables
     */
    public function getGlobals();
}

class_alias('Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface', 'Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface');
```

I followed their documentation for adding global vars: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#id1

Here is the changelog from Twig where it states the method as deprecated:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#extensions

What am I missing? Or is there a different approach adding global vars?

**Edit:**

After realising that I've completly missed the symfony error-log and the error coming for a totally different reason...

Errorlog:

```
[2019-06-13 15:49:18] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php line 49 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49)"} []
[2019-06-13 15:49:18] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php line 49) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49)"} []
[2019-06-13 15:49:18] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception: The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49)"} []
[2019-06-13 15:49:18] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php line 49 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49)"} []
[2019-06-13 15:49:18] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php line 49) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at /var/www/rekkt.de/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:49)"} []
```

**Edit2:**

So with the given errorlog this is what I've changed and it's working good now.

```php
public function getGlobals()
    {
        $globalVars = [];

        if (null !== $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            $globalVars['user'] = $token->getUser();
        }

        return $globalVars;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should no inject the whole container in your extension.

Always try to inject only what you need. In your example, you can inject directly the `AuthorizationCheckerInterface` instead of the `ContainerInterface`.

Concerning your error, without logs it's a bit touchy to guess, but you should try to check if the `getToken()` method is not returning `null` before calling `getUser()` on it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;


class GlobalVarsExtension extends AbstractExtension implements GlobalsInterface
{
    protected $em;

    protected $tokenStorage;

    protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }


   public function getGlobals()
   {
    $globalVars = [];

    if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        if (null !== $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            $globalVars['user'] = $token->getUser();
        }
    }

    return $globalVars;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just started with symfony two days ago and totally forgot about the seperate symfony logfile, just checked the apache-erroglog and wonderd why nothing relevant is in there. I'm updating my question with your improved code and the relevant error log.